# Using face detect in your program

Tags: android, camera, detection

Hey has anyone ever used the API for face detect in their android program?

More simply stated, can I have a java class that pulls up the camera, scans a person's face and returns parameters back into the program?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: +1 I'm also interested in hands-on experiences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw it being done in Javascript at:

http://badassjs.com/post/1461943420/face-detection-in-javascript-via-html5-canvas

It is using a common vision processing library, maybe you adapt what they've done to what you need. Surprisingly, it does seem to be that much code.